# onClick Button for different int event

Tags: java, android

I have a method with `int` parameter to `getResources` for a `listView`. I want to create a button to call one of each `int` one by one. How can I do that?

The method:

```
public void changeData(int i){

    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.tips_description_details);
    text.setText(descriptions[i]);
    String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.text_titles);
    textTitle.setText(titles[i]);
    imageTips.setImageResource(images[i]);
}
```

and this is the button's `onClick` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int tagId = (int)v.getTag();
    changeData(tagId);
}
```

Check out the docs for [getTag() and android:tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atag).